# Wireshark - Save decrypted ESP paquets to PCAP

Tags: encryption, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I am looking for an export function in Wireshark (or tshark, whatever) to save my decrypted ESP paquets (decrypted with SPI, AES128-CBC, HMAC-SHA1 keys).
Displayed paquets are decrypted but if I save them to a pcap file (With File > Save specific paquets), they are save as encrypted ...

Same with `tshark -r my.pcap --w out.pcap` ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether Wireshark supports such feature.

If the capture file was decrypted on PC1 and you want to see it on PC2, append your PC1's `esp_sa` file to PC2's `esp_sa` and add a newline to the end of PC2's `esp_sa`.

`esp_sa` is a text file and you can find it under

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark\
```